# Why does setting the width and height of pages to print not get applied?

Tags: c#, excel-interop, page-setup

I have this code to set various print options:

```
private void ConfigureByCustomerForPrinting()
{
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:" + 
        GetExcelTextColumnName(
            _xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count) + 
            _xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 100;
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;

    _xlSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
    _xlSheet.PageSetup.FooterMargin = _xlApp.Application.InchesToPoints(0.5);
}
```

When the sheet is generated, it respects the landscape orientation value but, as can be seen below:

[image]

...although width (wide) and height (tall) are set to 1 and 100, respectively, that is not the radio button selected. Instead, "Adjust to - % normal size" is set and selected. Why? I reckon this is probably fine, but the user wants it set to 1 and 100.

Comment: try setting Zoom to false before setting FitToPagesWide and FitToPagesTall

Comment: That did it; if you want to fill it out a little and make it an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `Zoom` property to `false` before sets `FitToPagesWide` and `FitToPagesTall`:

```
_xlSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
_xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
_xlSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 100;
```

From MSDN:

> If the Zoom property is True, the FitToPagesWide property is ignored.
>
> If the Zoom property is True, the FitToPagesTall property is ignored.